# ReactJs App component re-rendered from child's function

Tags: reactjs

I started learning react 2 weeks ago and im writing a phonegap app using react for my final project in college. i ran into a few problems today and found no answer for them. basically i have an auction component with a timer, a search component.
i keep the props for each auction in a state inside App which in turn renders a home page that renders all the auctions. the auction array is filled inside componentWillMount() in App(data from server). whenever i click the search button it starts an axios call inside Home (like wanted) and immediately goes to the axios call inside componentWillMount() in App which disable the search function. i tried stopping it with flags, shouldcomponentMount and more and couldn't fix, i would really appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

app component:

```
componentWillMount() {
    // Lifecycle function that is triggered just before a component mounts
    this.getAuctionsByParams([1, 2], 50, 900, 0);
    }
//call function to get auctions from serveer
    getAuctionsByParams(cities, lowPrice, highPrice, catCode) {
        const self = this;
        axios.post(auctionWS + 'GetAuctionByParam', {
            cities: cities,
            lowPrice: lowPrice,
            highPrice: highPrice,
            catCode: catCode
        }).then(function (response) {
            let res = JSON.parse(response.data.d);
            res.map(self.addAuction);
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

    },

//add auction to state array
    addAuction(item, i) {
        let arr = this.state.auctionsArr;
        let newAuction = {
            code: item.AuctionID,
            endDate: item.End_Date,
            price: item.Price,
            percentage: item.Percentage,
            prodName: item.ProdName,
            prodDesc: item.ProdDesc,
            imgArr: item.Images,
        }
        arr.push(newAuction);
        this.setState({ auctionsArr: arr });
    },
renderHome() {
    return (
        <Home offerBid={this.offerBid} auctionsArr={this.state.auctionsArr}/>
    );
},
```

Home component:

```
searchTriggered(cities, lowPrice, highPrice, catCode) {
    this.setState({ auctionsArr: [] });
    this.getAuctionsByParams(cities, lowPrice, highPrice, catCode);
}
//call function to get auctions from serveer
getAuctionsByParams(cities, lowPrice, highPrice, catCode) {//same func as in App - enters here with correct params}

//add auction from server to array
addAuction(item, i) {//same func as in App}

//function that returns a render of 1 auction
eachAuction(item, i) {
    return <Auction key={i} index={i} auctionfinished={this.deleteAuction} offerBid={this.offerBid}
        home="true" imgArr={item.imgArr} prodName={item.prodName} prodDesc={item.prodDesc} 
        price={item.price} endDate={item.endDate} code={item.code}
        percentage={item.percentage} />
}

//remove finished auction from displayed array
deleteAuction(i) {
    console.log(`delete: ${i} --- ${this.state.auctionsArr[i]} `)
    var arr = this.state.auctionsArr;
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({ auctionsArr: arr });
    this.state.auctionsArr.map(function(item,i){console.log(i + "____" +  item.endDate + ":::::::" + item.price)})
}

offerBid(i) {
    this.props.offerBid(i);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Swipeable onTap={this.openSearchModal}>
                <FontAwesome name='search' border="true" className="fa-3x" tag="div" />
                <Modal
                    isOpen={this.state.searchModalIsOpen}
                    onRequestClose={this.closeSearchModal}
                    contentLabel="open search``"
                    className="box" >
                    <Search closeModal={this.closeSearchModal} startSearch={this.searchTriggered} />
                </Modal>
            </Swipeable>
            <div className="container-fluid">
                {this.state.auctionsArr.map(this.eachAuction)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

EDIT: it turns out that for some reason whenever i press the search button the entire page (app.html) refreshed which causes that. i'm searching to find out the reason but if anyone has any idea as to what might cause that it would be very helpfull

**EDIT2:**
i found the problem, i had a FORM tag that caused the refresh